# Versioning websites

Tags: version-control, version, versioning

Is it useful to apply a versioning scheme like [SemVer](http://semver.org/) to a website? Or is it sufficient to somehow mark the deployed commits/revisions? For instance, create a Git release tag with a timestamp: `v2017-01-07T16:59:37+00:00` (especially in a continuous deployment environment, this approach seems more suitable to me).

Answer (score 0):

Depends, what you are trying to achieve?

If you are interested in cache control, indeed a git tag or a part of the git commit sha could be used.

Comment: Nothing special, I'd just like to know if something like SemVer makes sense when developing a website. Essentially, it's `vYYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss+TIMEZONE` vs. `vMAJOR.MINOR.PATCH`.